# Angular 12 breaks absolute paths for templateUrl and styleUrls

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12, angular13

I am using Angular 13, upgraded from Angular 11 but after upgrading to Angular 12, the absolute paths stopped working for templateUrl and styleUrls.

When I was with Angular 11, I had the AOT complier on and it was working.

I'm needing to use absolute paths because I want to avoid having long relative paths and a lot of my components are using shared `.scss` and `.html` files for showing delete/restore confirm dialogs etc.

Here's an example of what I currently have in the components for templateUrl and styleUrls which is not working in Angular 12+ but still working in Angular 11.

```
@Component({
    selector: 'something',
    templateUrl: '/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.scss']
})
```

If I change the above to use relative path like below then it works but it doesn't look nice to have so many `../../../`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'something',
    templateUrl: '../../../../example.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['../../../../example.component.scss']
})
```

This is the templateUrl error I'm getting:

```
Error: src/app/directory/directory/something.component.ts:9:18 - error NG2008: Could not find template file '/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.html'.

templateUrl: '/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.html',
```

This is the styleUrls error I'm getting:

```
Error: Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'C:/Users/.../frontend/src/app/directory/directory/something/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.scss?ngResource' in 'C:\Users\...\frontend'

Error: The loader "C:/Users/.../frontend/src/app/directory/directory/something/src/app/directory/directory/example.component.scss" didn't return a string.
```

I've also tried adding paths like below to my tsconfig but it doesn't affect anything.

```
 "paths": {
      "@env": [
        "environments/environment"
      ],
      "@shared/*": [
        "app/shared/*"
      ],
      "@core/*": [
        "app/core/*"
      ],
      "~*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    }
```

I've seen answers suggesting to use raw-loader but I'm not quite sure how it works and if that's even the right solution here. I think it might be a complier config problem but haven't figured anything out.

Here's what my angular.json looks like

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "newProjectRoot": "projects",
    "projects": {
        "frontend": {
            "projectType": "application",
            "schematics": {
                "@schematics/angular:component": {
                    "style": "scss"
                },
                "@schematics/angular:application": {
                    "strict": true
                }
            },
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src",
            "prefix": "app",
            "architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "outputPath": "dist/frontend",
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        ]
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "vendorChunk": false,
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "budgets": [
                                {
                                    "type": "initial",
                                    "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                                    "maximumError": "10mb"
                                },
                                {
                                    "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                                    "maximumWarning": "1mb",
                                    "maximumError": "10mb"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "browserTarget": "frontend:build:production"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "extract-i18n": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
                    "options": {
                        "browserTarget": "frontend:build"
                    }
                },
                "test": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
                    "options": {
                        "main": "src/test.ts",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
                        "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
                        "assets": [
                            "src/favicon.ico",
                            "src/assets"
                        ],
                        "styles": [
                            "node_modules/animate.css/animate.min.css",
                            "src/styles.scss"
                        ],
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
                            "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
                            "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "tsConfig": [
                            "tsconfig.app.json",
                            "tsconfig.spec.json",
                            "e2e/tsconfig.json"
                        ],
                        "exclude": [
                            "**/node_modules/**"
                        ]
                    }
                },
                "e2e": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
                    "options": {
                        "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
                        "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "production": {
                            "devServerTarget": "frontend:serve:production"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "defaultProject": "frontend"
}
```

Here's my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./src",
        "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
        "strict": true,
        "noImplicitReturns": true,
        "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "declaration": false,
        "downlevelIteration": true,
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "importHelpers": true,
        "target": "es2015",
        "module": "es2020",
        "lib": [
            "es2018",
            "dom"
        ]
    },
    "angularCompilerOptions": {
        "strictInjectionParameters": true,
        "strictInputAccessModifiers": true,
        "strictTemplates": true
    }
}
```

And here's my tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/app",
  },
  "files": [
    "src/main.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: did you find solution for this? , I am facing same issue

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact issue when moving from version 11 to 12. When I dropped the leading "/", it then was interpreted as an absolute path, relative to the workspace.